# Subprocess call bash script

Tags: python, bash, youtube-dl

Im trying to call a python class which contains a subprocess call for a bashscript.

```
def downloadURL(self,address):

        call(['bash youtube2mp3_2.sh', str(address)],shell=True)
```

This is the bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash 
# Script for grabbing the audio of youtube videos as mp3. 
address=$1
user_name=$2 # todo

path_music=/home/pi/music_loaded

echo  Address : $address

#title=$(youtube-dl --get-title $address)
youtube-dl --no-playlist  -x --audio-format mp3 -o $path_music/'%(title)s.%          (ext)s' $address
echo ----Download finshed----
```

When calling the method downloadURl I pass a static youtube link. Printing him in the python method returns it correctly.

But the echo in the script return "" in consonsole. So I think the Argument which I`am trying to pass is not passed to the script.

Does anyone have a Idea?

Comment: In addition to the fixes for the  Python code given in the available answer, that shell script is really quite awful. Consider running it through http://shellcheck.net/ and fixing what it finds.

Comment: Also, ideally, you shouldn't be calling `bash yourscript.sh`, but just calling `yourscript`, and letting the shebang (the `#!/bin/bash` line, in this case) be used to figure out what interpreter to use -- that way you can rewrite your program to be in a completely different language (or not to be a script at all but a compiled binary), and other programs calling it don't need to know or care.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

either you pass the arguments as a string

```
def downloadURL(self,address):
        call('bash youtube2mp3_2.sh '+address)
```

or as a list

```
def downloadURL(self,address):
        call(['bash','youtube2mp3_2.sh',address])
```

both work, but the latter is better so space chars are quoted if necessary.

(BTW since you prefix your command by `bash` you don't need the `shell=True`)

Third alternative: let the system choose which interpretor to use according to the shebang:

```
def downloadURL(self,address):
        call(['youtube2mp3_2.sh',address],shell=True)
```

PS: The args you're passing `['bash youtube2mp3_2.sh', str(address)]` make `call` add quotes to the first one because it contains spaces, well I don't know what the hell happens on Linux, but I tested on windows and I got a "syntax error", nothing got executed. (Works with the fixed code, I have MSYS `bash` in my path)

PS2: why calling such a simple bash script from python. Do it in python:

```
def downloadURL(self,address):
   path_music="/home/pi/music_loaded"
   rc=call(["youtube-dl","--no-playlist","-x","--audio-format","mp3","-o",os.path.join(path_music,'%(title)s.%          (ext)s'),address])
   if rc==0:
      print("Download OK")
```

Comment: the first solution wont work. the str cast was just a test and is not necessary. When removing the shell= true flag I got following error : OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory. Second solution  just shows no prints no log at all.

Comment: Suprising. That means that it doesn't even find `bash`. Works for me. Can you try the 3rd alternative?

Comment: Return this error : : 1:  : youtube2mp3_2.sh: not found
Does script work on your system?

Comment: it works, but maybe you're not in the directory you think you are in. See my last edit (PS2) that will get rid of all this useless bash (BTW my answers are tested and valid, it's just the environment that needs fixing, paths to your commands, etc...)

Comment: okay . added the absolut path to the script and the script starts. but again no adress param was passed to the script. BTW I run this on my raspberry

Comment: works here! Use the last option: drop the shell, it will work without it, python is way more powerful than a shell, you don't need it. It complexifies your toolchain.

Comment: Correct. Answer under PS2 works like a charm. Thanks guys :)

Comment: Good!! and you get an (almost) portable tool which can work on some other platform without bash (sorry I really don't know why it failed but let's be pragmatic: it was a not so good solution :))